# Changing background of button every second

Tags: java, android, button, timer, background

I have an activity with 8 buttons in it. I want the backgrounds for all the buttons to randomly change between each other every second that the activity is running. To do this I use the following code:

```html
public class CoinFrenzy extends Activity {

    private  int draw1 = R.drawable.buttonshape1;
    private  int draw2 = R.drawable.buttonshape2;
    private  int draw3 = R.drawable.buttonshape3;
    private  int draw4 = R.drawable.buttonshape4;
    private int draw5 = R.drawable.buttonshape5;
    private int draw6 = R.drawable.buttonshape6;
    private int draw7 = R.drawable.buttonshape7;
    private int draw8 = R.drawable.buttonshape8;
    private ArrayList<Integer> selector = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Button> buttonlist = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_coin_frenzy);
         Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.angry_btn);
         Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.angry_btn2);
          Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.angry_btn3);
         Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.angry_btn4);
         Button btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.angry_btn5);
          Button btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.angry_btn6);
         Button btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.angry_btn7);
         Button btn8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.angry_btn8);
        buttonlist.add(btn1);
        buttonlist.add(btn2);
        buttonlist.add(btn3);
        buttonlist.add(btn4);
        buttonlist.add(btn5);
        buttonlist.add(btn6);
        buttonlist.add(btn7);
        buttonlist.add(btn8);
        selector.add(draw1);
        selector.add(draw2);
        selector.add(draw3);
        selector.add(draw4);
        selector.add(draw5);
        selector.add(draw6);
        selector.add(draw7);
        selector.add(draw8);
        h.postDelayed(myRunnable, 1000);


    }

    public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

        // NOTE: Usually this should be a field rather than a method
        // variable so that it is not re-seeded every call.
        Random rand = new Random();

        // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
        // so add 1 to make it inclusive
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

        return randomNum;
    }

    private Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    private Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (Integer x : selector) {
                int randomInt = randInt(0, 7);
                int back = selector.get(randomInt);
                Button currbtn = buttonlist.get(randomInt);
                currbtn.setBackgroundResource(back);

            }

            //run again in one second
                h.postDelayed(myRunnable, 1000);

        }};
```

However, after one second passes my app crashes without any logcat errors.

Comment: you dont need to write whole code in runnable..just write code to change background

Comment: you are doing UI stuff on background thread

Comment: @r7v So how should I solve this?

Comment: create your layout in a XML or in if you want to do it programatiicaly do it in the onCreateMethod and run a thread which passes a random color , use  runonUIthread() while changing the background of the button

Comment: @r7v I have the layout in XML already, now I'm just accessing the buttons and changing the backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

First do these 2 things:

1. You have to remove change the background of the button code from thread. This is the main cause of crash.
   Below you can find two methods on how can one run a code on the main/UI thread on android:
2. runOnUIThread Activity’s method

   ```
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           // change background color here
       }
   });
   ```
3. Handler

   ```
   Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
   handler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         // UI code goes here
    }
   });
   ```

you might want to use one of the two methods whenever you want to update the UI like updating colors on views or other UI related stuff. Otherwise, the application might crash because the UI classes on Android are not thread safe.

This will help you!!

Comment: I updated my code in the question, however now it just loads the activity and then nothing changes.

Comment: In your runnable you are always assigning to a button with index randomInt,  a drawable with the same index randomInt. I.e. you are always changing drawable to the same as in beginning

Answer (score 0):

Replace your

```
private Handler h = new Handler();
```

to

```
private Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

otherwise your code will be run outside the UI thread

Comment: I updated my code in the question, however now it just loads the activity and then nothing changes.

Comment: Try to move postDelayed from onCreate into onResumed

Comment: I did, no change. I don't think that's the problem as before with the previous code it would wait 1 second and crash which means it would attempt to execute the runnable, now it just doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass dynamic index into

```
int randomInt = randInt(0, 7);
```

you are always passing same values for min is 0 and max is 7, so it doesn't change any background.

Use selector random ids replace 7 with dynamic loop value x.

```
private Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (Integer x : selector) {
                int randomInt = randInt(0, x);
                int back = selector.get(randomInt);
                Button currbtn = buttonlist.get(randomInt);
                currbtn.setBackgroundResource(back);

            }

            //run again in one second
                h.postDelayed(myRunnable, 1000);

        }};
```

It would be helpful to you.